# Energy Generation through magnets

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, orbital-motion, home-experiment

Lets say we had two magnets, one much larger than the other. Then we put the larger one in the center and force the smaller one into an orbit around the large one using the magnetism force as the centripetal force. I'd assume the magnets would have to be spheres and on a flat, low friction surface to cancel out external forces. Using the correct weights, radius, and magnetic pull, how much electrical energy would possible to take out of a machine, with kinetic generators, the size of lets say a tire and how much, on the ambitious end, would be possible from the size of a nuclear power plant?

It's 1 am and I was just curiously in bed thinking of this. The materials seem feasible and minimal. Thanks in addition for your responses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero. No arrangements of magnets and weights will give you any electrical energy, aside from recovering the work it takes to build that arrangement. In which case, why not skip the magnets and spin a turbine instead?

You can't make energy out of nothing, even if magnets are involved.

Comment: but you use kinetic generators to turn the motion of the magnet revolving around into electrical energy. Much like you turn the motion of water in a watermill into electrical.

Comment: I'm not saying to turn the magnetic force into energy, but rather use the magnetic force to make an orbit, which in turn you can make the motion into electrical energy.

Comment: @JacksonMiranda You have to spend energy to get the magnets moving. If the kinetic generators take energy out, then you have to put more energy in to keep the orbit. The very best you can do is break even, and realistically you can't even do that.

Comment: so magnets wont be able to keep up the velocity as the kinetic generator takes energy. Basically the magnet will continuously slow down until it stops

Comment: Yep, that's about it.

Comment: @JacksonMiranda As for thanking me, "thank you" comments are discouraged on this site. If you want to thank me, click the green check mark next to my answer to accept it. (Although I would encourage you to wait to see if any more answers come in first.)